# PHP PSR-2 new lines before/ after statments

Tags: php, coding-style, psr-2

Example no 1:

```
$something = [1,2,3,4]
foreach ($something as $key => $value) {
    //code code code
}
$something2 = [];
```

I can't find clear answer about new live before and after foreach, what PSR-2 say about that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Point 2.3 "Lines"](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#user-content-23-lines) Make it optional to add blank lines before and after statements. It is still useful to separate code blocks in "paragraphs" to improve logic comprehension and readability.

> Blank lines MAY be added to improve readability and to indicate related blocks of code.